# How to list kinds in datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just had to figure this out for my own application, so reposting the answer here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Time has passed since this was asked and answered. Now there's a simpler way.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html

```
q = Kind.all()
for kind in q.fetch(100):
  print kind.kind_name
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def GetSchemaKinds():
    """Returns the list of kinds for this app."""

    class KindStatError(Exception):
      """Unable to find kind stats."""

    from google.appengine.ext.db import stats
    global_stat = stats.GlobalStat.all().get()
    if not global_stat:
      raise KindStatError()
    timestamp = global_stat.timestamp
    kind_stat = stats.KindStat.all().filter(
        "timestamp =", timestamp).fetch(1000)
    kind_list = [stat.kind_name for stat in kind_stat
                 if stat.kind_name and not stat.kind_name.startswith('__')]
    kind_set = set(kind_list)
    return list(kind_set)
```

Reference: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/f2e7568040c015ff

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that this answer is for the older `db` api. The new `ndb` api has another way to get all `Kind` listed here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata#get_kinds