# How to Fetch all Entity Types in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, orm, metadata

How can I retrieve all of the entity types from the datastore in appengine? For examaple, in my ORM I have defined:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  # fields here...

class Employee(db.Model):
  # fields here...
```

I want a way to get "Employee" and "Person" in a list, but not the actual data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list kinds in datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541945/how-to-list-kinds-in-datastore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html and look for

```
q = Kind.all()
```

That's the snippet you need.

Comment: The easiest answers are almost always the first ones missed! Thanks!

Comment: You should post this answer to the question this is a duplicate of, since things have changed since that question was posted.