# Is there a way to get a list of all google datastore "KIND" using queries

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I would like to get a list of `KINDS` from my google app engine datastore using queries (`GQL` maybe?). For example the way one would simply `show tables` of a database.

I have looked at a similar question ([How to list kinds in datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541945/how-to-list-kinds-in-datastore)), however it does not solve my problem as it is python specific.

I am currently using a GDS library in PHP (https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) that helps me fetch data from GDS if I know the Entity name using `"SELECT * FROM Kind"` GQL query.

I am currently in a situation where I may not know the name of the Entity KIND which I need to fetch data from hence the need to get the list of Entity KINDS which I can then look through and confirm if the entity exists, then run my select query.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please remember there are no tables in the database.  Have you looked for similar answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541945/how-to-list-kinds-in-datastore

Comment: Yeah @tim, I am aware there are no tables. However, I would like to know the KINDS in the database if there is a way to do that preferably using GQL.

Comment: As the answer I referred to shows you can query for kinds. However not using GQL. Why use GQL ? it's not necessary.

Comment: The answer linked by @TimHoffman is for `db`, not `ndb`. My answer below is current for `ndb`.

Comment: Please edit your question to have a single, self-contained body that doesn't need to be read as an incremental list of corrections.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternate approach based on GQL... This returns a list of the Kinds available:

```
SELECT * FROM __kind__
```

In theory, you can then obtain the schema for this object by listing the associated properties for a given Kind (e.g., Person):

```
SELECT * FROM __property__
WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY(__kind__, 'Person')
```

If you are using Google's library to issue these queries, then you will have to set the **`AllowLiterals = true`** property in your request to avoid getting an exception with an error detail saying `Disallowed literal: KEY`.

Also, since the `property_representation` values are overloaded for things like Dates vs Integers, then you can only use the type data as a guess of the underlying type, possibly using conventions.  As you cursor through the data, you could update the type information.  It's curious that there isn't a better way since Google's Datastore UI provides type information when you create a new instance of an Entity.

Answer (score 2):

You can query them Using the metadata objects of ndb.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata#get_kinds